# Finding number of divisors faster

Tags: python, beginner, programming-challenge, python-3.x

Here is my code:

```
triangle_numbers = []
number = 0
for i in range(0, 10000):
    number = number+i
    triangle_numbers.append(number)

for number in triangle_numbers:
    number_of_divisors = 1
    for i in range(1, int(number/2)+1):
        if number % i == 0:
            number_of_divisors = number_of_divisors + 1
            if number_of_divisors > 500:
                print("FOUND AT ", number)
```

It takes forever to return the answer. How do I make it faster? I'm a beginner, so if you could walk me through your answer that would be great!

The challenge that I am doing is [Highly divisible triangular number -
Problem 12](https://projecteuler.net/problem=12).

Comment: You might want to have a look at [previous Q&A's](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/search?q=euler+12+%5Bpython%5D) about the same problem.

Answer (score 3):

You are searching for a number with more than 500 divisors in the range 0 to 10000. But we are not sure whether a number less than 10000 will be the required number. So, instead of searching a number in a range, we can search for that number which satisfies the condition the in the set of positive real numbers.

```
num=1
tnum=0 #representing triangular number
nof=0
while nof<501:
      nof=2 #to include 1 and the number itself
      tnum+=num
      num+=1
      for i in range (2,int((tnum/2))+1):
          if tnum%i==0:
             nof+=1
      print (tnum," : ",nof) #printing the triangular number and its number of divisors
print ("Required number is ", tnum)
```

This code will also take a good amount of time to get you result.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of trying every number less than `N/2` you should use fundamental theorem of arithematic and reduce `N = (p1 ^ a1) * (p2 ^ a2) ... (pn ^ an)` then total divisors will be `tau(N) = (1 + a1) * (1 + a2) ... (1 + an)`

- Load primes (Generate using a seive or read a file)
- For each number take primes pi less than N and find ai
- Take product after adding one

Answer (score 1):

Not a true answer to your question (regarding performance), but here's two things to think about:

- *range()* will, if called with one argument, assume *0* as first argument, so there's no need to explicitly call *range(0, x)*.
- There's a more pythonic way of adding any type *x* and *y* together:
  *x += y*

And other operations on *x* and *y* include:

```
x -= y    # Instead of x = x - y
x *= y    # Instead of x = x * y
# (...)
```